# Data Visualization component is missed in the UI Kitten

Tags: react-native

I'd like to use the React Native UI Kitten framework but I couldn't find a data visualization component -bar chart, progress bar for example- in the components, which is essential to my application.

The question is, can I integrate/include data visualization lib into UI Kitten? or is there React Native framework that already supports data visualization elements?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Data Visualization UI Libraries that work quite nicely with UI Kitten. One of such is [Victory](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/native).